# Why does PostgreSQL require its own user/group for installation?

Tags: postgresql, mac-os-x

When installing PostgreSQL via MacPorts (and I assume via other means too), a `postgres:postgres` user/group is created. Are there any reasons why this user/group is needed?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The reason is that it is wise to run the database processes under a separate account.  At least one advantage of this is that the OS processes as safer in the case of the database server being hacked.  On the other side the database related files are safer from the 'normal' user accounts too - the PostgreSQL cluster (or at least its data) is relatively easy to destroy with a well-aimed single-file deletion.

If you check your `passwd` file you may find lots more similar users for other services, I imagine on similar grounds.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I had a look at the `passwd` file and it contains lots of users that start with underscore. Actually the PostgreSQL and MySQL users also start with underscore (e.g. `_mysql:*:74:74:MySQL Server:/var/empty:/usr/bin/false`). Is there a specific reason for that?

Comment: @drop-shadow This [question](http://superuser.com/questions/191330/users-in-etc-passwd-on-mac-os-x) may shed some light on it - basically the passwd file _is not_ the place the user accounts are stored, still there are entries (at least for some) of them.